# Python: copy line, conditional criteria

Tags: python-2.7, copy

I have been searching for following Python solution to copy selectively lines from 1 txt file to another. I can copy the whole file, but with only a few lines I get an error.

My code:

```
    f = open(from_file, "r")
    g = open(to_file, "w")
    #copy = open(to_file, "w") # this instruction copies whole file
    rowcond2 = 'xxxx' # look for this string sequence in every line

    for line in f:
        if rowcond2 in f:
            copy.write(line,"w") in g # write every corresponding line to  destination

    f.close()
    # copy.close() # code receive error to close destination
    g.close()
```

So without the rowcond2, I can copy the whole file. Yet with the condition nothing is written to destination file.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is exactly rowcond2 is supposed to do? Or what kind of condition you're willing to have?

Comment: 'rowcond2' stands for a string sequence in a line of txt file (e.g. 'xxxx').

Answer (score 0):

Why not to put your condition inside the for loop?

```
for line in f:
    if condition:
        copy.write(line)
```

Comment: This helps! My coding is still confused between the 2 files. With your suggestion, I have corrected code (see my 1st entry).

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve this case searching on SO:

[Using python to write specific lines from one file to another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755587/using-python-to-write-specific-lines-from-one-file-to-another-file)

@Lukas Graf: thank you for your detailed step wise explanation.