# Regex for middle position Replacing

Tags: regex, parsing, textmate

I want to replace following string

```
comments={ts=2010-02-09T04:05:20.777+0000, comment_id=529590|2886|LOL|Baoping Wu|529360}
```

in

```
comments={ts=2010-02-09T04:05:20.777+0000, comment_id=529590, user_id = 2886, comment='LOL', user= 'Baoping Wu', post_commented=529360}
```

My approach is comment_id=.([0-9])* for the first replace
Its difficult for me for the other replaces. Can anyone help me?

Comment: what programming language do you use? are you able to do a substitute operation?

Comment: I am not using programming language, but TextMate from Apple Mac

Comment: TextMate uses Oniguruma regex syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform all these transformations with one search and replace operation. Use the following regex that has *capturing groups*:

```
(comment_id=)(\d+)\|(\d+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|(\d+)
```

Replace with `$1$2, user_id = $3, comment='$4', user= '$5', post_commented=$6`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fP0fS9/2)

- `(comment_id=)` - Group 1, a literal character sequence
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `\|` -  a literal pipe symbol
- `(\d+)` - Group 3 matching another portion of digits
- `\|` - again, a pipe
- `([^|]+)` - Group 4 capturing one or more symbols other than `|`
- `\|` - again, a pipe
- `([^|]+) - Group 5 capturing one or more symbols other than`|`
- `\|` - another pipe
- `(\d+)` - Group 6 matching another portion of digits

In the replacement string, `$n` are backreferences to the captured groups.

Comment: Thanks:). My dataset is too big to test it on this website. Do you know how i can test it with a python script

Comment: At [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/fP0fS9/3), you can get that Python code: go to the *code generator* section (see the left bottom pane). Python code sample is at the bottom. Note that Python backreferences are of the ``\`` + `digit` form. The replacement will be `\1\2, user_id = \3, comment='\4', user= '\5', post_commented=\6`.

Comment: I had try it on IDLE. I got a syntax Error as follows:     p = re.compile(ur'(comment_id=)(\d+)\|(\d+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|(\d+)')
                                                                        
SyntaxError: invalid syntax Because of this symbol '

Comment: Sorry, right now I am on a bus and can't check but the syntax is correct. Write `import re`, then declare a `s = "your string"`, then check with `print(re.sub(r'(comment_id=)(\d+)\|(\d+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|(\d+)', r"\1\2, user_id = \3, comment='\4', user= '\5', post_commented=\6", s))`. In real life, youyou'd want to read the file line by line though and write modified lines to a separate file.

Comment: Note I have put the pattern between single quotes and the replacement pattern between  double quotes.

Comment: Thanks, now I want to use it on multiple lines with open('<Path>') as f:
    for line in f:
        p = re.compile(ur'(comment_id=)(\d+)\|(\d+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|(\d+)')
        subst = u"\1\2, user_id = \3, comment='\4', user= '\5', post_commented=\6" But it doesnt work...Can you help me

Comment: Please see [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755587/using-python-to-write-specific-lines-from-one-file-to-another-file0) it should help. If not, I will help you once my kids go to bed in a couple of hours.

Comment: Since you got help with Python in [another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609601/optimization-of-parsing-of-python-scripts) please consider finalizing this question.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
comment_id=.*?(?=,)
```

[example](https://regex101.com/r/dU5lQ3/106)