# Optimization of Parsing of Python Scripts

Tags: python, regex

I want to apply regex for every newline in my txt file.
For example

```
comments={ts=2010-02-09T04:05:20.777+0000,comment_id=529590|2886|LOL|Baoping Wu|529360}
comments={ts=2010-02-09T04:20:53.281+0000, comment_id=529589|2886|cool|Baoping Wu|529360}
comments={ts=2010-02-09T05:19:19.802+0000,comment_id=529591|2886|ok|Baoping Wu|529360}
```

My Python Code is:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(comment_id=)(\d+)\|(\d+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|(\d+)', re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
#open =
test_str = r"comments={ts=2010-02-09T04:05:20.777+0000, comment_id=529590|2886|LOL|Baoping Wu|529360}"
subst = ur"\1\2, user_id = \3, comment='\4', user= '\5', post_commented=\6"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
print result
```

I want to solve it with help of MULTILINE, but it doesnt Work.
Can anyone help me

The Output for the first line should be

```
comments={ts=2010-02-09T04:05:20.777+0000, comment_id=529590, user_id = 2886, comment='LOL', user= 'Baoping Wu', post_commented=529360}
```

My issue is only to apply the regex for every line and write it on txt file.

Comment: what doesn't work?  What's the error or the output you're getting vs what you actually want?

Comment: Is it not doing it globally? I don't see a need for multiline or dotall.

Comment: @sln I have thousands of lines in the txt file. Thats why it is important for me

Comment: Should be able to `loop: read in next line, do regex on line; write new line to another file; end loop`

Comment: Yes, that was my idea with file in line. But it doesnt work. Did you solve it

Answer (score 1):

Your regex works without having to use MULTILINE or DOTALL.  You can replace through the entire document at once. [In action](https://regex101.com/r/dR2aX4/1)

```
import re

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    txt = f.read()

pattern = r'(comment_id=)(\d+)\|(\d+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|(\d+)'
repl = r"\1\2, user_id = \3, comment='\4', user= '\5', post_commented=\6"

result = re.sub(pattern, repl, txt)
with open('file2.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(result)
```

Comment: I had tried it out, but it doesnt apply the replacemts. It is the same file

Comment: Hmm, works for me.  Did you notice that it's writing out to a separate file?

Comment: Ah, Ok...one Moment. Should I create a file with the name file2.txt?

Comment: Which python version did you use? The compiler gave me an error on the line with the declaration of the variable "pattern". He said invalid syntax with the symbol '

Comment: python27.  Try without the `u`, it shouldn't be needed here.

Comment: IT WORKSSSSSSSS:))))))))). Thank you very much. But why without the u? What is the reason

Comment: @OkanAlbayrak: See [*What exactly do “u” and “r” string flags do in Python, and what are raw string literals?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l). `u` is necessary if you work with extended characters, from all of the Unicode table. Glad to hear it finally works.